# ORA-65100: missing or invalid path prefix when opening newly built PDB

Tags: oracle, docker

After successfully executing the following;

CREATE PLUGGABLE DATABASE R237
ADMIN USER R237 IDENTIFIED BY R237
ROLES = (dba)
DEFAULT TABLESPACE R237_DATA
DATAFILE '/opt/oracle/oradata/ORACLE19C/R237/R237_DATA.dbf' SIZE 2400M AUTOEXTEND ON
FILE_NAME_CONVERT = ('/opt/oracle/oradata/ORACLE19C/pdbseed/',
'/opt/oracle/oradata/ORACLE19C/R237/')
STORAGE (MAXSIZE 5G)
PATH_PREFIX = '/opt/oracle/oradata/ORACLE19C/R237/';

Which it creates the R237 subdir under /opt/oracle/oradata/ORACLE19C/ just fine and places the initial .dbf's in the directory.

However, when I try to open the database with;

alter pluggable database R237 open;

I get;

ORA-65100: missing or invalid path prefix - /opt/oracle/oradata/ORACLE19C/R237/
65100. 00000 -  "missing or invalid path prefix - %s"
*Cause:    The path prefix was missing or invalid.
This can also happen if any of the following are true:
- The directory path specified by PATH_PREFIX clause contains the
string '..' or an invalid path separator like // or exceeds the
maximum length supported on host operating system.
- The target path already exists as a file in operating system.
- The ROOT container (CDB$ROOT, when connected to a pluggable
database or application root, when connected to an application
container) has a PATH_PREFIX set and either NONE or a directory
location outside ROOT containers' PATH_PREFIX was specified.
*Action:   Correct the PATH_PREFIX clause and reissue the statement.

None of the suggested fixes seem to be relevant

Comment: I was able to create the PDB without the PATH_PREFIX parm and it appears to have written the files in a new R237 subdir, so perhaps when you creater a PDB from a seed you cannot specify the PATH_PREFIX?  Not sure but it worked

Comment: Where is the PATH_PREFIX value for PDBs stored?